# How to set state in a React component using this.setState without explicitly passing the field name to update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form in my component with many input fields that update local state through an event handler called "handleFieldEdit".

I want to set local state to whatever the user is typing into the input field, but I don't know which field the user will using, so I attempted to set state this way:

```
handleFieldEdit(event) {

        this.setState({
            event.target.name: event.target.value
        });

}
```

This does not work. I think this can be solved with a simple Javascript syntax trick, but the react method setState is throwing me off. How should I set state this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
```